# Use of the colons in the REST URI instead of slash

Tags: rest, google-api

Google documentation describes how to use colons for the custom method names.
The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/custom_methods) says:

> The reason to use : instead of / to separate the custom verb from the resource name is to support arbitrary paths. For example, undelete a file can map to POST /files/a/long/file/name:undelete

I didn't get how this is better to support arbitrary paths.
For me both support arbitrary paths:

```
POST /files/a/long/file/name:undelete
```

or

```
POST /files/a/long/file/name/undelete
```

Correct me please if I am wrong

Answer (score 3):

> I didn't get how this is better to support arbitrary path

I think what they are arguing is that, without the colon convention that they are using, there is ambiguity

```
POST /files/a/long/file/name
```

is "name" part of the identifier for the /files/a/long/file/name resource? or is it instead a "custom method" that should be applied to /files/a/long/file resource.

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint ideally should be nouns

```
/pets
/store/orders
/users
```

There are well-known verbs/actions such as retrieve (HTTP GET), create new item (HTTP POST), update an item (HTTP PUT), update partially an item (HTTP PATCH) and delete an item (HTTP DELETE).

But there are some verbs or action with no clear category, hence the document suggest using colon e.g

```
/pet:findByStatus (instead of /pet/findByStatus)
```

Comment: GetPetsByPetStatusId/{petStatusId}